# Watching historical performance data using benchmark.js and a build process

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, karma-runner, benchmark.js

Is there any `node.js` module that runs `benchmark.js` and compares previous results (historical data stored in a file) raising warnings if performance changes beyound a certain threshold?

I'm aiming for something similar to what is currently achieved when installing karma, jasmine and code coverage (istanbul).

I have already built a crude version of this benchmarking process using require.js to load various benchmarks for modules separately (similar to unit teting). `PerfRunner.html` runs the benchmarks and the blank page gets filled with text data:

```
new Collection() x 3,727,840 ops/sec ±1.48% (95 runs sampled)
collection.add() x 687,129 ops/sec ±23.36% (65 runs sampled)
```

Currently I'm looking for changes in the data by eye, but obviously it's impractical to keep track of all this data by hand.

If no module is available, some hints about how this could be configured using currently available tools (node, gulp, karma, etc) would be useful.